# Catching Error when using Task.Factory

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i am using the following

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoPrintConfigPage(serial));
```

then the function i am calling looks like this

```
private void DoPrintConfigPage(string serial) 
{ 
    //do printing work 
}
```

My problem is an exception is being thrown inside the thread and not being handled.

I have tried wrapping it in a try catch

```
try
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoPrintConfigPage(serial));
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

but it still is not catching the error and thus crashing the application.

How can I catch exceptions in the main thread so I can handle them?

### Update

I have made the changes recommended below and still it is saying the exception is unhandled

```
var task =  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoPrintConfigPage(serial))
                               .ContinueWith(tsk =>
                               {
                                  MessageBox.Show("something broke");
                               },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

then in my `DoConfigPage` I added another try catch.

In this catch is now where it is crashing and saying the exception being thrown was unhandled, what am I missing?

```
private void DoPrintConfigPage(string serial)
{
    try
    {
        //call the print function
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;   //it is crashing here and saying it is unhandled
    }
}
```

I also tried what Eric J. suggested with the same results

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoPrintConfigPage(serial));

try
{
    task.Wait();                  
}
catch (AggregateException ex) { MessageBox.Show("something broke"); }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Alternatively, you can chain your task creation and add a ContinueWith:

```
var job = Task.Factory
    .StartNew(...)
    .ContinueWith(tsk => 
         {
              // check tsk for exception and handle
         });
```

EDIT: This snippet, when run, pops up the message box for me:

```
void Main()
{
    var serial = "some serial";
    var task =  Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => DoPrintConfigPage(serial))
        .ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("something broke");
            var flattened = tsk.Exception.Flatten();

            // NOTE: Don't actually handle exceptions this way, m'kay?
            flattened.Handle(ex => { MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message); return true;});
        },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

}

public void DoPrintConfigPage(string serial)
{
    throw new Exception("BOOM!");
}
```

Comment: Of note is the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` parameter you can add so that the continuation only runs when there is an exception, effectively making it act like a `catch` block.

Comment: @servy Good call; I always forget about that

Comment: See updated code, i attempted this and it still isn't handling it.

Comment: That isn't what you want to do - all you're doing now is throwing a different exception in the continuation; If you want to handle any exceptions in the continuation itself, you'd check `Task.IsFaulted`, then the `Exception` property - but regardless, you are still `try`/`catch`ing in the wrong place - you'll wrap the thing that waits for the task to complete, not the creation.

Comment: Thanks I got it..It was still showing an unhandled exception while debugging but when running not debugging it worked just fine and did what I needed it to do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's no need to check `IsFaulted` if you have `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`, you know it will be true.

Comment: @Servy Derp - I forgot to remove that when I was fiddling with the script in LINQpad...I'll edit it out of here.

Comment: @twaldron (Feb 14'13 at 22:00): To achieve this behaviour also during the debugging phase, "Just my code" should be deactivated in the debug options. See under: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 12):

Your `try` block is exited right after you start the new task, because that method just continues to run.

Instead you can catch the Exception as an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) where you wait for the task (or multiple tasks) to complete:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    throw new MyCustomException("I'm bad, but not too bad!");
});

try
{
    task1.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // Assume we know what's going on with this particular exception. 
    // Rethrow anything else. AggregateException.Handle provides 
    // another way to express this. See later example. 
    foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
    {
        if (e is MyCustomException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

Answer (score 7):

If you are not waiting on your task, I think the easiest solution is found in [Task.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets the AggregateException that caused the Task to end prematurely.
>   If the Task completed successfully or has not yet thrown any
>   exceptions, this will return null.

I am using something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoStuffHere())
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.Exception != null)
            Log("log all the exceptions!");
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You should also know about 
[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you are in the business of creating "fire and forget" `Task` instances, you'll want to subscribe to that event at the start of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to catch a [Corrupted State Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx). Since .NET 4 applications are unable to catch such exceptions by default. You could try to add the `legacyCorruptedState­­ExceptionsPolicy=true` entry to your configuration file as stated in the MSDN article linked above.