# Does try/catch work outside of Task.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Will the following catch an exception that occurs inside of StartNew()?  It doesn't seem to.

```
   try
   {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
       //do something
      });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      //log it
    }
```

Comment: `Will the following catch an exception that occurs inside of StartNew()` : No. The try will exit as soon as the new task is started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Your try block will exit after the new task is created.

You can catch exceptions though. Please see:
[Catching Error when using Task.Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883850/catching-error-when-using-task-factory)
for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It can't because when the `try` is exited the task has not completed yet. No way of knowing whether an exception will occur in the future or not.

The whole point of tasks is to start an asynchronous, independent computation.

Comment: Also, the task executes on a different thread, so even if it did finish before the end of the try block it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Yeah. I tried to show a logical contradiction why it cannot possibly be the case that the catch is hit. You don't have to know anything about the TPL to come to that conclusion.