# WaitAll(Task[ ], TimeSpan) won't rethrow exception from a task

Tags: c#

I created a task array and trigger `WaitAll` with `TimeSpan`

If a task takes more than the timeout, the `Exception` thrown by other thread is not re-thrown

Like in sample code below, first thread sleeps for 7 seconds and other for 5 seconds then throws `Exception`. I would expect the `catch` to rethrow the `Exception`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This one will sleep");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Snoozed for 20 seconds");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }));

    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting afresh");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            throw new Exception("Can't wait any longer");
        }));
    try
    {
       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         throw;
    }  
}
```

If however both the threads finish in the `TimeSpan`, then error is thrown

I wish to understand how `WaitAll` exceptions work

**EDIT**

More info on my requirement:

I have 2 tasks - one initiates an I/O

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    WriteFile(filePath, fileSize);
}));
```

Other one reboots the machine on which I/O is initiated, verifies that machine is rebooted within 45 minutes else throws exception

```
 tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {                
     InducePanic();
     WaitForReboot(new TimeSpan(0, 45, 0));   # This method throws Exception if >45 minutes
     ....
```

The `WaitAll` is like this

```
 try
 {
     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0));
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     if (!ex.Message.Contains("System.IO.IOException"))
         throw;
```

The trouble is that task 2 `throws Exception` if reboot doesn't finish within 45 minutes. But task 1 is still ongoing

After 60 minutes, the code just proceeds further and the `Exception` is lost

Comment: maybe can help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883850/catching-error-when-using-task-factory

Comment: If you use a timeout it's not going to wait around to see if one of the task eventually throw an exception.  It should return false so you'll know that one or more tasks are still running.

Comment: @juharr Well one of the threads in my case did throw an exception. The other one was ongoing, so I was expecting that `WaitAll` will rethrow the exception of that other thread

Comment: It's basically all or nothing.  Either all the tasks finish and it will throw an aggregate exception or it hits the timeout in which case it cannot just give you the exceptions on the tasks that have finished since there might be more to come on the unfinished tasks.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question with more details on what my current issue is

Answer (score 0):

`WaitAll` will bring exceptions out of your tasks while it's active, however when the timeout is reached it ends. It will not keep listening to your tasks to see if they're going to throw an exception after that.

If you want to keep monitoring them for exceptions, you can append a `.ContinueWith` to the tasks in question yourself, and check if the previous task faulted to get the exception.

Comment: Agreed, but the other task did error out after 5 seconds. First one was still continuing, so I was expecting that it would have collected the status for second task , catch and rethrow Exception

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am solving this. I do not like it, but anyways

```
try
  {
    bool tasks_finished = false;

    tasks_finished = Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0));

    if (!tasks_finished)
      foreach (var ongoing_task in tasks.ToArray())
        {
          if (ongoing_task.IsFaulted)
            throw ongoing_task.Exception;
        }
  }
catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ...
    throw;
  }
```

**Note**:

This solution would work only when one of the threads has `faulted`. If both are still ongoing, the solution fails